# Cannot fetch data from yahoo finance, on google collaboratory

Tags: python, yfinance

I know there has been a change on Yahoo finance for fetching data but I dont know how to fix it for my program on google collaboratory. To get the data I am using this code:

```py
    df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end='2021-04-15')
    df
```

I then get an error saying cannot fetch code, is there any fixes or an alternative I can use?
This is the error:

> RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end='2021-04-15')
> 2 df

Comment: Always share full error traceback.

Comment: I have now added it, can you help me at all?

Comment: That's strange. I ran your code and it worked flawlessly. I think the issue lies with your version. My `pandas_datareader` version is `0.10.0`. Try running `pip install -U pandas-datareader` on your cmd/terminal and updating the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your pandas_datareader to .10  (`pip install pandas_datareader --upgrade`)

With pdr 0.9 you'll get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-de79fadf5dea> in <module>
      1 import pandas_datareader as pdr
----> 2 df = pdr.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end='2021-04-15')
etc.
```

With pdr .10 you'll get

[image]

The fix was documented here:
https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew.html

```
Bug Fixes

- Fixed Yahoo readers which now require headers
```

Many thanks to the Pandas team for fixing this so quickly!